# Getting Error when I install AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources through Nuget and simply run the target application

Tags: nuget, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Getting following error repetitively when I install the `AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources` package through `Nuget` installer

Error 101 The pre-application start initialization method Start on type `AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources.PreApplicationStartCode` threw an exception with the following error message:

The type initializer for 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitResourceManager' threw an exception.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Himanshu

Comment: user3821497 = Himanshu

Comment: Could you specify, what VS vesion, .NET Framework version you are using?
Also, what type of project do you create and what version of NuGet package(s) do you install?
Do you use control bundles? Where do you host your application (IIS Express, VS Web development server, IIS)?